# YouTube Authentication by GWT Client

Tags: java, gwt, authentication, youtube-api

I am developing a GWT application with YouTube integration.  As a first step, I need to be able to authenticate the GWT app to YouTube API and I am not sure how to go about this as there seems little published information on this.  After authenticating, I will need to upload videos to YouTube on my app's behalf (not users').

**How can I authenticate my GWT app to YouTube API (preferably on the client-side)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should handle authentication/authorization using OAuth 2. I don't do GWT development, so I haven't personally used this library, but this is what a Google search turned up: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-oauth2/

You should not be uploading videos into a single master account. Instead you should use the OAuth 2 tokens you get back after the user authorizes access, and upload videos into each user's account. There is more information about why this is the recommended approach in this blog post: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/02/video-uploads-from-your-sites-community.html

Comment: Thank you for your response, Jeff.  One question: Is the use of a single master account discouraged or disallowed?

Comment: Discouraged, and it can lead to the problems brought up in that blog post. I'm afraid that I'm not going to offer any advice as to how you can set things up to use a single account given that we don't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff.  I'm glad I asked this question before starting development :)